# Purge mysql and it's configuration completely from MAC.

Tags: mysql, linux, mac-os-x

I, by mistake messed up with mysql's only user and the situation is I can't create new user or  give more privileges to existing one. Access denied is the error. Only visible db is `info Schema` So I decided to remove mysql from my MAC and install it again. For removing completely(including config data) I tried [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436425/how-do-you-uninstall-mysql-from-mac-os-x).

After installing again, I see my configuration is the same. And I have the same user who can't do anything and the only database visible to him is `info schema`. `mysql` database is not visible either.

**How can I completely remove configuration including user privilege data of mysql from MAC ?** Command like `sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.*` I am new on MAC, is there any command like we have for linux `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common`.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to purge anything, you just need to [follow these instructions to reset the administrator password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html). If you happened to delete the admin user, just create a new one on the init file:

```
create user root@localhost;
grant all privileges on *.* to root@localhost;
```